# Android: I can't figure out SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have tried and tried, but I cannot get my RSS app to properly format the pubDate into a more user friendly format.

```
    String str = "26/08/1994";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //please notice the    capital M
  Date date = formatter.parse(str);
```

That code looks simple enough, but I get an unhandled type parse exception error on formatter.parse(str).  Once that gets working, I then need to convert my RSS Pubdate to MM/dd.

The line of code to set the text for that is here:

```
  listPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate());
```

Do I just change that to:

```
  listPubdate.setText(date);
```

This looks so simple that it's driving me nuts that I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are actually *running* this and getting the error. As others have pointed out, the problem is you need to wrap the `formatter.parse` call in a try/catch block. This is a ***compilation problem***, not a runtime problem.

The code you have will work as you expect once you fix this compile problem.

Use a second formatter to get the MM/dd output you want.

```
    String str = "26/08/1994";

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //please notice the    capital M
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");

    try {
        Date date = inputFormatter.parse(str);
        String text = outputFormatter.format(date);
        listPubdate.setText(text);
    } catch (ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This was it!!! Wow, I've spent 12+ hours on this.  - How do I mark this has the answer?  Stackoverflow has saved me.  This was my final code:   String str = (myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate()); 

  SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"); //please notice the    capital M
  SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");

  try {
      Date date = inputFormatter.parse(str);
      String text = outputFormatter.format(date);
      listPubdate.setText(text);
  } catch (ParseException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: @tjberte SO truly is a great place, welcome. Click on the checkmark beside an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the date by this

```
// get the current date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

and want to put in simple format then

```
String date=String.format(mDay+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mYear);
```

so you can use this very easily.

Answer (score 1):

> I get an unhandled type parse exception error on formatter.parse(str)

For that, you'll need to explicitly handle the exception, either by declaring that the currently executing method just throws it, or by catching it.  For more information, I highly recommend going through [the Exceptions Lesson in the Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Here's an example of catching the exception.

```
String str = "26/08/1994";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //please notice the    capital M
Date date;
try
{
  date = formatter.parse(str);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
  // Handle error condition.
}
```

Comment: For the second question concerning display format of the date, you could just use another SimpleDateFormatter.   
 SimpleDateFormat displayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd"); 
      String displayDate = displayFormatter.format(date);

Comment: I have to be close.  Here is what I have now and I am getting a force close when I fire up my app.    SimpleDateFormat displayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd"); 
  String displayDate = displayFormatter.format(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate());
  listPubdate.setText(displayDate);

Comment: To troubleshoot the force close, take a look at the error message in logcat.  Also, troubleshooting, code readability, and code maintenance are often all easier tasks when one line of code is just doing one thing.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateformat.parse(String) throws a checked exception... wrap it in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code ... pay attention to format inside SimpleDateFormat Constructor. This string which to be parsed for date should be similar in format to that of string passed in SimpleDateFormat constructor

public Date getDate(String str) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date d = null;

```
    try {

        String str1 = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(" ")).substring(0,
                str.lastIndexOf(" "));
        String str2 = str1.substring(0, str1.lastIndexOf(" "));
        Log.v("str1", str2);

        d = sdFormat.parse(str2);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return d;
}
```